# Multiple Camera view showing same camera feed

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios4

I want to show multiple Camera view on a screen.But when i create two object of AVSession or imagepicker one grab camera and other show blank screen .
is there any way to show multiple camera views showing same feed ?

Comment: why you need to camera as same output will be displayed same on both

Comment: See the app picture frame or nostaligio

Comment: there is option to show camera in all frames ... it show same camera view in 3 4 different views

Comment: I am facing the same problem. Maybe you have to duplicate the original feed somehow.

Comment: how is it possible ? any pointers ? @iMasa

Comment: Any body there ? please its urgent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to show multiple views of the same feed, you need a single `AVSession` with an `AVCaptureVideoDataOutput`.

It's pretty much as described here:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1702/_index.html

When processing each video frame you will assign the image it contains to multiple `UIImageView`s (or `CALayer`s, if you prefer...) when handling `captureOutput:didOutputSampleBuffer:fromConnection:`. That way you get multiple renderings of the same feed.

See the [AVCaptureVideoDataOutput Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVCaptureVideoDataOutput_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for more information. Also see pretty much any piece of sample code that uses `AVCaptureVideoDataOutput` and simply tweak `captureOutput:didOutputSampleBuffer:fromConnection:`.